# How to send hibernate connection info to logback

Tags: logback

I want to get hibernate conncection info (like driver_class, url, username, password) in logback file. (Not manually)

This belows is my logback file.

```
<appender name="dbAppender" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.db.DBAppender">
        <append>false</append>  //unfortunately it does not work.
        <connectionSource class="ch.qos.logback.core.db.DriverManagerConnectionSource">
            <driverClass>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</driverClass>
            <url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:aaa</url>
            <user>bbb</user>
            <password>ccc</password>
        </connectionSource>
    </appender>
```

It works. But I want to get information about connection info(like driver class, url, user, password) from hibernate.cfg.xml automatically in logback.xml.

Your cooperation would be appreciated.

Please Help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Getting the values out of your `hibernate.cfg.xml` would probably require writing some code. However, if you externalise all your hibernate properties in a properties file you can [import them into your logback configuration](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html).

Hibernate supports using a properties file called `hibernate.properties` in the root of the classpath, or you could pass an instance of `java.util.Properties` to `Configuration.setProperties()` when configuring your session factory.

If you can get your hibernate properties into a properties file you can use it from logback like so:

### properties file on the classpath

```
<configuration>
  <property resource="hibernate.properties" />

  <appender name="dbAppender" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.db.DBAppender">
    <append>false</append>  //unfortunately it does not work.
    <connectionSource class="ch.qos.logback.core.db.DriverManagerConnectionSource">
        <driverClass>${hibernate.connection.driver_class}</driverClass>
        <url>${hibernate.connection.url}</url>
        <user>${hibernate.connection.username}</user>
        <password>${hibernate.connection.password}</password>
    </connectionSource>
  </appender>
</configuration>
```

If your properties aren't on the classpath you can use `<property file="path/to/some.properties" />` instead.